# Repeating part of Keras model, depending on number of inputs

Tags: keras

I'm trying to use part of Google Deepminds CGQN network in Keras ([Deepmind Paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjg-oWIlpfdAhWBLVAKHasmCOAQFjAAegQIABAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeepmind.com%2Fdocuments%2F227%2Fconsistent_generative_query_networks.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2-n9e1k3pL1Hbn0QNawf99)). Depending on how much input images they give to the network, the network understands more about the 3D environment it is trying to predict. Here is an scheme of their network:

[image: CGQN network scheme]

I would also like to use multiple input "images" like they did with the M<sub>θ</sub> network. So my question is: Using Keras, how can I reuse a part of the network an arbitrary number of times and then sum all of the outputs it generates, which will be used as an input to the next part of the network?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using the [functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/), I'll just give a proof-of-concept here:

```py
images_in = Input(shape=(None, 32, 32, 3)) # Some number of 32x32 colour images
# think of it as a video, a sequence of images for example
shared_conv = Conv2D(32, 2, ...) # some shared layer that you want to apply to every image
features = TimeDistributed(shared_conv)(images_in) # applies shared_conv to every image
```

Here [TimeDistributed](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/#timedistributed) applies a given layer across the time dimension, which in our case means it applies to every image and you'll get an output for every image. There are more examples in the documentation linked above and you can implement a shared set of layers / submodel and then apply that to every image and the take the reduced sum.

Comment: Could you also explain what the smartest way is to sum the outputs form the TimeDistributed?

Comment: How about `Lambda(lambda x: K.sum(x, axis=[axis you want to sum over])(features)`, something like that to some across the axis would work.

Comment: Thats what I had indeed, but thought keras might had a built in approach. Thanks anyway!